# A PHP substring issue

Tags: php, substring

I got a simple php issue which is that I don't know how to use substring here...

```
ABCDEF[RAND NUMBER 1-10000000]GH
```

And so I need to get that random number using substring,

I dont know if my brain works correctly today but I really couldnt figure how to do that.

Comment: my expected output is as i said that random number. also i didnt tried any code because i have no idea how to do that

Comment: So you need 1-10000000 ?

Comment: Are the letters exactly as you wrote above, than you can go with strpos to determine the start and the end of the number by searching for "F" and "G". Otherwise I would go for an regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is always better in this case but If your string pattern is fixed like ABCDEF123456GH, you can simply use substr like

```
$str = "ABCDEF432465GH";
echo substr($str, 6, -2);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This does exactly what the OP wants - extracts the random number from the string with offsets. As you may see the example in the question is rather stupid one not describing the context so it well may be there are other digits around the string, so this solution may be the only one correct as regexes mentioned above won't work.

Comment: Not to mention that performance wise string functions are *times* faster than regular expressions.

Comment: @CodeBird I am calm, mate, this is just one of those situations where a simple solution is considered bad/wrong by someone because it's simple, so I try to point people to be more mindful about it :)

Answer (score 3):

This will do, no need for `substr` or anything:

```
$string='ABCDEF432465GH';
echo preg_replace('/[a-z\[\] ]*/i', '', $string);
```

https://eval.in/136918

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger done, I didn't think that the `[]` are actually in there

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are better when you don't know where in the text is desired substring,

```
$string = "ABCDEF10000000GH";

if (preg_match("/(\d+)/", $string, $m)) {
  print $m[1];
}
```