# Input value/enable just last 10 characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, input

In input form can I use just the last 10 characters when I submit a form?

For example, this link: `http://linkwebiste.com/test?x=123456789012` woulc be the value on an `input` box (like search) and I'll submit, but I just require `123456789012`.

I want the results of input form to be in another page, like `<form action="page2.php" method="post">`

There are 2 images for example (in photoshop, created by me):

[image]

Comment: So you want to get only the first 11 characters? Then answer is use substr(0, 11) or something similar. This will cut off anything over the 11th character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A PHP substring issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081754/a-php-substring-issue)

Comment: You've got an answer already. I failed my syntax haha

Comment: @OvidiuCristianPrisacaru Does this work? `$last11 = substr($mystr, -10);`?

Comment: Sidenote: `?x` is a GET method and you're using `<form action="page2.php" method="post">` - method needs to be "get".

Comment: Don't work with GET, just with POST.

Comment: you've been given answers below. ask them now

Comment: `<form action="results.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="clearfix">

     <input type="search" name="search"  placeholder="Enter link"  onkeyup="Allow()">
     <input type="submit" value="Convert now" class="button" onclick="insert()" />

    </fieldset>

   </form>`

Comment: This is code. If someone use `http://linkwebiste.com/test?x=123456789012` in input , i want to display just last 11 characters in results page.

Comment: Work ! Thank you.I put syed code in input form first time, but need to put in results form. Heh. Thank you again. `<?php
$_POST['search'] = substr($_POST['search'], -11);
echo $_POST['search']
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with a -Ve number on the 2nd argument.

```
$postedString = "http://linkwebiste.com/test?x=1234567890"
$lastString = substr($postedString, -10);
echo $lastString; //will result "1234567890"
```

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought it was substr(0, 10). Forgot that that was substring() that took 2 integers.

Comment: Thank you sir. Work ! `<?php
$_POST['search'] = substr($_POST['search'], -11);
echo $_POST['search']
?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`substr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) method with a negative offset:

```
$last11 = substr($mystr, -10);
```

From the Manual:

> If `start` is negative, the returned string will start at the `start`'th character from the end of string.